# If $g(\cdot,\cdot)$ is linear in the second argument, is it necessarily $g(x,u) = f(x)u$ for some $f$?

Tags: functions

Let $g: \Omega \times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function which is linear in the second argument. Does it always follow that $g(x,u) = f(x)u$ for some $f:\Omega \to \mathbb{R}$?

$\Omega$ here is a bounded domain.

Comment: $f(x)+au+b$ is also linear in $u$.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Set $f(x) := g(x,1)$ and use linearity.

Answer (score 2):

Write $f(x)=g(x,1)$, $g(x,u)=g(x,u.1)=g(x,1)u$

Answer (score 1):

Yes. For a given $x\in\Omega$, consider $g_x:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$. This is a linear map, hence there is some $f_x\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $g_x\left(u\right)=f_xu$ for all $u\in\mathbb{R}$. Then define $f\left(x\right)=f_x$, and you get the desired function.

(I assume that linear means $g\left(x,au+bu'\right)=ag\left(x,u\right)+bg\left(x,u'\right)$).